# What does "You might want to put 30% down for yourself" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the movie [Law Abiding Citizen](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1197624/), there is this dialog when Clyde is having meal in the cell at about 48 minutes:

> Clyde: Oh, excuse me, waiter?
>
> [The waiter looks at Cyde]
>
> Clyde: *You might want to put 30% down for yourself*, my man.
>
> [The waiter kind of nods and leaves]

What does "You might want to put 30%  down for yourself" mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I haven't seen the film, but I would interpret the sentence as: *You might want to add 30% of the bill (as a tip) for you.*

Answer (score 4):

"Put down" refers to "putting down a value of 30% in the spot for the tip on the bill".

More generally, "put down" means "write" similarly to "write down".  A longer form would be "put down on paper", for example.